# iOS Google AdsMob - <Google>[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new(nil)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob, google-ads-api

I need some help.

As described in the Title, the Google AdsMob does not work properly.

I built the app according to the tutorial, however i receive the above mentioned error
**plist:**

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>app id from google</string>
```

Viewcontroller:

```
private let banner: GADBannerView = {
    let banner = GADBannerView()
    banner.adUnitID = Banner ID
    banner.load(GADRequest())
    banner.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
    return banner }()

viewDidLoad(){
banner.rootViewController = self
        view.addSubview(banner)
}
```

It seems that it doesn't matter wether the banner.view is created or not. The app shows a black screen an error message is:

[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil),

I am working with a Macbook Air M1

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: i have same issue now, looking for help from hero, big thanks :)